# Update ui android with different activities

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am doing a project in Android where in the MainActivity I am calling a WebService to get a json object. I need to do this operation every 30 minutes. To doing that I am using a handler.

From the MainActivity I can call at least 5-6 activities showing diffrent kinds of graphs.

My problem is that if I am in a activity X and my MainActivity is refreshing the json every 30 minutes, how can i update the graph if i am already in the activity??? I dont want to finish the activity and enter again.

Thanks for ur help.

Comment: What graph library are you using? Does re-rendering the graph or resetting the data not refresh it?

Comment: It is mpandroidchart.

Comment: You could utilize a BroadcastReceiver class that you register inside of each activity individually to receive a broadcast that you send whenever the new data is pulled. That way you can detect the response from any activity, not just your MainActivity.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [Dynamic & Realtime data](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Dynamic-&-Realtime-Data)? It discusses refreshing the graphs

Comment: Yes i have read the documentation @cricket_007, the problem is that in MainActivity I call my webservice to get the json and I draw a graph in another activity. If I had the information in the same activity I am sure that it is viable but in this case we have different activities comunication issues.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, Android can kill Activities at any moment to clear memory for itself, so just holding onto them simply to refresh their data seems like a bad idea. I think the BroadcastReceiver is a good solution, and then just use Intent Extras to send the JSON to an Activity to render it. Without seeing code for what you are trying to do, though, it's hard to give a definite answer.

Comment: I completly agree to use a BroadcastReceiver, i will try to implement it in my app and will update you.

Thanks to @cricket_007.

Comment: Can somebody help me to implement the BroadcastReceiver between activities? I pretend when my Asyntask finish in Main Activity I could update my Activity X which is already running.